# Is there a way to paste one table onto the end of another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two of the exact same table (one is in an archive database and the other in a regular database). My goal is to merge all of the data into one table. I am thinking that the `insert` into the function is what I should be using, but also wondering if it should be `join` or `merge`.

The code I have tried for the insert into is:

```
Insert into [DMSArchive].[dbo].[VEHICLE_TRANSACTION] 

(CAST(TRANS_DATE_TIME as DATE) Date             
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER = 0 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "HOV"             
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 1 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 15300                
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 30000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 55999              
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 65000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 199999             
THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "ExpressPass"             
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 15301 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 29999                
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 56000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 64999              
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 200000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 299999                
THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "CDecal"              
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER > 299999 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "Unknown"                
,COUNT (HOV_TAG_NUMBER ) as "Total Vehicles")

SELECT              
CAST(TRANS_DATE_TIME as DATE) Date              
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER = 0 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "HOV"             
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 1 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 15300                
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 30000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 55999              
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 65000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 199999             
THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "ExpressPass"             
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 15301 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 29999                
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 56000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 64999              
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 200000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 299999                
THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "CDecal"              
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER > 299999 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "Unknown"                
,COUNT (HOV_TAG_NUMBER ) as "Total Vehicles"                                
                
FROM [DMS].[dbo].[VEHICLE_TRANSACTION]              
Where TRANS_DATE_TIME >= '2019-01-01'               
                
GROUP BY                
CAST(TRANS_DATE_TIME as DATE)               
                
ORDER BY Date
```

It seems to me that this should work without any error, however, I get the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

I have tried adding commas, taking away, and parentheses. I would love any ideas!

Comment: You can’t define target columns with casts etc and you probably don’t want to do casts in the source data either. You need to declare the columns themselves. Or if they’re identical in structure just `insert into table1 select * from table2`

Comment: Look at the documentation for an [`INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement for whatever database you're actually using. (The error looks like SQL Server, not MySQL).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question should be answered by consulting product documentation or an available online tutorial.

Comment: INSERT INTO targettable SELECT ... FROM sourcetables ...

Comment: Is this for MySQL or SQL Server? I removed the inconsistent tags, so you can re-tag appropriately.

Comment: Is there a way for me to keep this code that deals with tag numbers and date while inserting? Where would it go in a INSERT INTO targettable SELECT ... FROM sourcetables type format?

Comment: Not sure what engine you *want* to use but, according to the error message, the one you *currently* use is SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The target table column names has to be defined instead of casting the values.

First check whether this query works

```
SELECT              
CAST(TRANS_DATE_TIME as DATE) Date              
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER = 0 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "HOV"             
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 1 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 15300                
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 30000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 55999              
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 65000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 199999             
THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "ExpressPass"             
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 15301 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 29999                
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 56000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 64999              
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 200000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 299999                
THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "CDecal"              
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER > 299999 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "Unknown"                
,COUNT (HOV_TAG_NUMBER ) as "Total Vehicles"                                

FROM [DMS].[dbo].[VEHICLE_TRANSACTION]              
Where TRANS_DATE_TIME >= '2019-01-01'               

GROUP BY                
CAST(TRANS_DATE_TIME as DATE)               

ORDER BY Date
```

If the above works:

I assume the column names of `[DMSArchive].[dbo].[VEHICLE_TRANSACTION]` are as : `[Date],[HOV], [ExpressPass],[CDecal], [Unknown],[Total Vehicles]`
If they are not, please use that in the columns list after the table name in insert.

```
Insert into [DMSArchive].[dbo].[VEHICLE_TRANSACTION] 
( [Date],[HOV], [ExpressPass],[CDecal], [Unknown],[Total Vehicles])

SELECT              
CAST(TRANS_DATE_TIME as DATE) Date              
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER = 0 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "HOV"             
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 1 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 15300                
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 30000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 55999              
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 65000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 199999             
THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "ExpressPass"             
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 15301 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 29999                
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 56000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 64999              
OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 200000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 299999                
THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "CDecal"              
,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER > 299999 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "Unknown"                
,COUNT (HOV_TAG_NUMBER ) as "Total Vehicles"                                
                
FROM [DMS].[dbo].[VEHICLE_TRANSACTION]              
Where TRANS_DATE_TIME >= '2019-01-01'               
                
GROUP BY                
CAST(TRANS_DATE_TIME as DATE)               
                
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: @mohlensehlen, as you commented (and later deleted) - isn't this working?

Comment: The code from the first box is working, however, the second set with insert into function is not. I am working in SQL Server 2008. Do you see any new functions that might not have been introduced yet?

Comment: What are the columns and their data types of `[DMSArchive].[dbo].[VEHICLE_TRANSACTION] `? put that in your question, also put some sample data of `[DMS].[dbo].[VEHICLE_TRANSACTION]`